# "super" keyword cannot access parent property in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, super

```
class Base{
    constructor(val){
        this.val = val;
    }
    basep = 'default1';
    basef(){
        return 2;
    }
}

class Test1 extends Base{
    constructor(val,name){
        super(val);
        this.name=name;
         
    }
    getp(){
        console.log(this.name,this.val);
        console.log(this.basep); //(in case of proerty) result: 'default1'.  if "this" is changed to "super" ===>  result: undefined
        console.log(super.basef()); //(in case of methods) this and super both work.
    }
}

test= new Test1(1,3);
test.getp();
```

In java 'this' and 'super' worked both fine to get parents property but it seems in javascript only this works.
why is the difference?

Comment: What exactly is the result you expect and why? Do you expect `super.basep` to yield the same result as `this.basep`?

Comment: I was expecting the result to be 'default1' when access base.p 
I understand how they work behind the scenes in JS now. Still thanks to you for trying to help!

Answer (score 2):

In Java, attribute names are put in a scope, and you can have two different attributes with the same name if they were created by different classes. This is not how it works in JavaScript with prototypical inheritance at all, though.

In JavaScript, data properties (that are created by assignment) are owned by the object itself. The parent constructor created the `.basep` property directly on the child instance. `this.hasOwnProperty('basep')` will be `true`.

The `super` keyword is used to access properties on the parent's `.prototype` object, regardless of what the current `this` value is, but still allows calling them on the `this` object. The `basef` method lives as a property on `Base.prototype`, `basep` does not.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I just learned how prototypes in JS work and you answer really helps.